# Socket.IO using Blackberry Dynamics Cordova API

Tags: javascript, cordova, socket.io, good-dynamics, blackberry-dynamics

I have a Cordova App that uses Socket.IO for communication with the server.

I would like to make the app compatible with the Blackberry Dynamics which appears to have a number of plugins that replace the common methods of connecting to the server e.g. the GDHttpRequest for API calls.

Will I have to re-write my app to use RESTful API calls or is there another way allowing me to keep Socket.IO?